Is the set $\{\nabla \psi: \psi\in C^\infty(M)\}$, with $M$ a complete, compact and connected Riemannian manifold a Frechet space?
I know that $C^\infty(M)$ is a Frechet space. How do I know if its image under $\nabla$ is still a Frechet space?

The definition of a Frechet space is not just a real or complex vector space: you need a topology, typically in the form of a family of seminorms.
